# Doctrine one to one JOIN

Tags: sql, doctrine

I have class `Account` and class `Request` and have one foreign key `accountId` in my `Request` table. Need to select data from DB in format:

```
 Request.id, Request.name, Request.url, Request.created, 
 Request.accountId, Account.email (depends from accountId)
```

For this operation I've created sql, that works pretty good.

```
 SELECT Request.id, Request.name, Request.url,  
 Request.created, Account.email 
 FROM Request
 LEFT JOIN Account
 ON Request.`accountId` = Account.id
```

But I cannot create right DQL to select the same data.

**Please help to construct DQL Query**. I have not found any helpful information in Doctrine documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT r.id, r.name, r.url, r.created, r.email 
 FROM Request r
 LEFT JOIN r.account a
```

But, before you execute the query you need to create the modeling (entities) with the association between them.

Comment: Thanks I've read about Doctrine One-To-One Associations and everything works.